# Regex match the Domain name

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I need to match the domain name form the string .With three different pattern.

```js
var str=" with http match http://www.some.com and normal website type some.com and with www.some.com  ";
var url = /(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?/g;
console.log(str.match(url))
```

Above snippet match only with `http://www.some.com`.

But i need to match with three types.

1. `http://www.some.com`
2. `www.some.com`
3. `some.com`

Help me find the result.I am not very well in regex.I get this regex pattern from stack overflow. But the not satisfied with three conditions.

Comment: just group `(...)` the prefixes and use optional operator `?`

Comment: see my answer, there is a demo for it as well

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
(?:(http|ftp|https):\/\/)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&;\/~+#-])?
```

this just makes the http/ftp/... optional (without capture `?:`)

see example here: [demo](https://regex101.com/r/x7TrQJ/1)

or as graphic [here](https://regexper.com/#(%3F%3A(http%7Cftp%7Chttps)%3A%5C%2F%5C%2F)%3F%5B%5Cw-%5D%2B(%5C.%5B%5Cw-%5D%2B)%2B(%5B%5Cw.%2C%40%3F%5E%3D%25%26amp%3B%3A%5C%2F~%2B%23-%5D*%5B%5Cw%40%3F%5E%3D%25%26amp%3B%5C%2F~%2B%23-%5D)%3F)

Comment: Note! The `&amp;` matches `&` (ampersand), `a`, `m` , `p` and `;` separately. Not intended I guess ;) Just use `&`.

Comment: I know, i just copied the regex from asker

Answer (score 1):

As said before, you can make some parts of the regex optional with `()?`, for example : `(http:\/\/)?(www\.)?(some\.com)`. So with your code, maybe something like this :

```js
var str=" with http match http://www.some.com and normal website type some.com and with www.some.com but matched http://----.-.-.-. and now will match ----.-.-.-.";
 var url = /((http|ftp|https):\/\/)?[\w-]*(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?/g;
 console.log(str.match(url))
```

But the regex you provide matches strings like `"http://----.-.-.-."`, and with this modification it will now match `----.-.-.-.` for example, which is not what you want.
If you are really trying to match a URI, you need to use a different regex.

Here are some resources to help you improve this answer :
https://regex.wtf/url-matching-regex-javascript/

see [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url) where the RFC is quoted : http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3987.html

Note : they all seem to match `"http://----.-.-.-."`, so maybe your regex is not much worse.

Answer (score 0):

To match Unicode characters, you should use this one:

```
(ftp:\/\/|www\.|https?:\/\/)?[a-zA-Z0-9u00a1-\uffff0-]{2,}\.[a-zA-Z0-9u00a1-\uffff0-]{2,}(\S*)
```

[Demo here](http://regexr.com/3ep9g)

Answer (score -1):

```js
var pattern = /((https|http|ftp){1}:\/\/)?(www\.)?\w+\.\w{2,4}/ig;
var test = ['http://www.some.com/NotRelevant',
  'https://www.some.com/NotRelevant',
  ':/www.some.com/NotRelevant',
  'www.some.com/NotRelevant',
  'some.com/NotRelevant'
];
for (var t = 0; t < test.length; t++) {
  console.log(test[t], test[t].match(pattern));
}
```

Comment: also matches `:/www.some.com`